# Excel documentation custom number formatting

Tags: excel

I'm looking to format numbers in Excel. For example:

- 123.23 <-- green (positive decimal)
- 123    <-- yellow (no decimal)
- -2     <-- black (negative)
- N/A    <-- grey (otherwise)

I don't think the above is possible with a direct custom number format. The closest 'official docs' I could find is: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5.

How could the above be done? And is there a more definitive guide to the custom number formatting in Excel than the above link?

Comment: This could be achievable with Conditional Formatting

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad cool, on another note do you know where the 'official' docs would be to describe their custom number formatting? is there some pdf somewhere that describes it?

Comment: Questions, "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" are not on scope for this forum.

Comment: @ScottCraner sure, there's still a valid question here that can be addressed regarding conditional formatting, and in the answer it can point to the docs for more information, no?

Comment: You are talking about color but looking for number format. Number format never changes any color.

Comment: @Harun24HR sure, it does: `[Blue]#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00);0.00;"sales "@`. Did you not view the link I posted?

Comment: @David542 Wow! Its new to me. I didn't know this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be achieved with conditional formatting. Here are the steps to do so (repeat for each separate rule):

1. Highlight the entire relevant range
2. Go Home->Conditional Formatting->New Rule->"Use formula to determine which cells to format"
3. Enter a formula for each rule (be sure to remove absolute references, and reference the first cell in the range)
4. Go Format->Fill->Choose color you want

To get you started, the first rule would be something like `=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".", A1)))>0`, second rule something like `=ISERROR(SEARCH(".", A1))`, third rule `=A1<0`, and fourth rule `=A1="N/A"` .

I'm sure there are cleaner ways, but it works.